# Probability of a sum being above a threshold in a n dimensional vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am having a problem measuring a certain probability. Suppose a n-dimensional vector a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,...,a<sub>n</sub>. What are P(a<sub>1</sub>+a<sub>2</sub>+...+a<sub>n</sub> < 1) , P(a<sub>1</sub>+a<sub>2</sub>+...+a<sub>n</sub> = 1) and P(a<sub>1</sub>+a<sub>2</sub>+...+a<sub>n</sub>  > 1) equal to? a<sub>i</sub>s are all inside [0,1]  but we don't know anything else.

Comment: Iam not sure if we can answer that actually. If we suppose uniformity inside [0,1] ?

Comment: If the $a_i$ are not uniform, but are independent and identically distributed, then for large $n$ we can apply the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) and approximate the sum by a normal distribution.

Comment: But about this normal distribution and its μ,σ? Is it possible to have any further knowledge?

Comment: Assuming $A_k \sim R(0,1)$ this link can help, but it's not very cute: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformSumDistribution.html